# Java unique ID generator

Tags: java, database

How to generator unique order id for customer order, check mysql primary keys.
I need ids like this,

1. OID000001
2. OID000002
3. OID000003

When 2 clients open order form next id shown as `OID000004` but when save 2 oders I got error - primary key duplication.

I need when 1st client open order form id should be `OID000004` and 2nd client's order form id should be `OID000005`.

How to fix this bug?

Comment: can you use uuid? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Comment: what are you using JPA Hibernate JDBC your question is really not clear

Comment: Just use an autoincrement column, and format the number it generates as you desire when displaying it (if you really want to display it)

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned **MySQL**. If you are using **SQL**, you can use  `AUTO_INCREMENT` to automatically assign id's when a new one is added to the database.